# Sargassum seaweed affects porcelain?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

[image]We are inundated with Sargassum seaweed here in the Virgin Islands right now. It has a pungent sulphur odor as it decomposes. Coincidentally (or NOT) the porcelain tubs in the condos I work at are all turning brown. Some are not used at all and still this stain is appearing and it appears to be beneath the surface, or at least you can't FEEL it, it feels smooth. It "cleans" in contact with bleach, but reappears later. 
What chemical reaction could be occurring and is it perhaps sargasso related or just coincidence?

Comment: Interesting question, but it doesn't seem to me that there is enough information to give an answer. I'll point out that the stain can't be "undersurface" since bleach cleans it. // Question - Where is the source of fresh water? Desalination or groundwater?

Comment: Desalination. And thank you, the surface must be porous, or course, but to the touch, it is smooth and the stain detectable by touch alone.

Comment: All that can be said is that there are many desalination processes. I'd assume that distillation is not used since it would be the most energy consuming. Now the desalination would lower mineral concentrations (eg NaCl) to be fit for human consumption and also be treated for bacterial contamination. So I'd expect the water to be fit for human use, but it wouldn't be "pure water" like you'd get from distillation. What might be different in the water now would be a complex research project. // All in all, you could be right that there is a difference...

Comment: No water has touched the tub in my office. It is not used, so the water isn't the issue. It seems to be coming from the air and the only environmental change we are aware of is the sargasso grass that is deteriorating in the marina and the beach nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! [Dimethyl sulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_sulfide) (DMS), $\ce{H3C-S-CH3}$, structurally, is given off by some marine algae. It's volatile, with a boiling point ~37 °C: just about normal body temperature. It's odor is as you describe, sulfury, resembling cooked cabbage.

As a wild guess, could your condo be air-conditioned or the porcelain fixtures be cold? The [maximum sea water temperature at British (and U.S.) V. I.](https://seatemperature.info/june/united-states-virgin-islands-water-temperature.html) is ~29 °C in June, and it's likely some DMS would evaporate at that temperature, perhaps condensing on cold fixtures and serving as a [nutrient for archaea and bacteria](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/2741/)? Try warming a section of the tub, perhaps with a *waterproof* heating pad, to see if that prevents condensation and subsequent discoloration.

DMS itself should be a clear, colorless liquid at room temperature, but [bacterial slime](http://www.netafimusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/WWTSBACT_Iron-Bacterial-Slime.pdf), particularly iron-sulfur (which turns to *sulphur* in BVI) metabolizing critters, produce a reddish-brown deposit. And underneath that porcelain is probably a cast-iron tub. So if bleach blasts away that brown, it might be debris from a biofilm.

If that is the case, then at last be consoled that you've got some of the same [bacteria and archaea as found in Yellowstone National Park](https://microbewiki.kenyon.edu/index.php/Yellowstone_Hot_Springs).

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, the discoloration is eliminated with chlorine beach, but it reappears overnight. It is not detectable by touch and doesn't rub off. The tubs ARE ceramic over cast iron and the surface glaze may have been compromised by cleaning compounds, exposing the metal microscopically (?) but not visibly. Is the archaea and bacteria harmful to humans? It is not possible to rub away this stain so it does not SEEM to be on the surface. Is that the nature of a biofilm?

Comment: No, these archaea and bacteria are not harmful, AFAIK, though in water pipes they can cause clogs. To remove iron stains, there are commercial products such as Iron Out and Red-B-Gone. These have to sit for a while on embedded stains in porcelain. Though more effective at first, avoid cleaners with HF, hydrofluoric acid, which is toxic and dissolves the porcelain glaze.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has helped us assuage the  our owners concerns and certainly helped me in formulating an intelligent response to their inquiries!